# Getting an error while attempting to checkout with SharpSVN

Tags: c#, svn, sharpsvn

While attempting to use the following code, I am receiving the following error : Already working for different url, error code 155000.

```
string targetPath = @"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\CPM Creator\"; //" for prettify

client.Authenticatio​n.DefaultCredentials​ = new NetworkCredential("guestUser", "hjk$#&123");

// Checkout the code to the specified directory
client.CheckOut(new Uri("http://svn.peerlis.com:8080/CPM Creator"), targetPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, is it correct? Is this already the working path for a SVN folder? Are there any hidden svn folders in that location?

I use SharpSVN in a "get to scratch area, work locally, throw away" cycle, so I always start with a clean (empty) folder (with no SVN folders in the ancestors). This has always worked fairly well.

Comment: Marc, thats a good point I guess this is where my lack of knowledge of the product comes in. I thought it would/could work like a update or merge which is what I really need to do. To answer your question yes there are hidden svn folders.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the best way to troubleshoot SVN problems is to use the command line client.  Sometimes, it offers more clues that way, so you might want to look at documentation on [svn checkout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re04.html)

Answer (score 1):

You said there are hidden .svn folders; this means that `targetPath` is already a working copy, you'll have to check out to another folder, or delete the existing working copy if it's no longer needed.

In case you want to do an update of the existing working copy do something like:

```
client.Update(targetPath);
```

Check out the [Subversion docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) for more info on what command you need in what case.